# Different date time in results of search

Tags: loop, search, date-time

In my *search.php* file i have a loop which succesfuly gives list of search query.

```
    global $wp_query;
    $total_results = $wp_query->posts; 

    if ( $total_results ) : 
        foreach ( $total_results as $tr ) : 

        //(...)

        endforeach;
    endif;
```

But there is something wrong with date time in results because `the_time()` function displays a wrong date for all listed posts. Here is what i get:

`the_time( 'j F Y, G:i' ); // --> 7 NOVEMBER 2023, 20:00 (don't know what kind a date is that)`

`echo get_the_date( 'j F Y, G:i' ); --> 7 NOVEMBER 2023, 20:00`

`echo $tr->post_date; // --> 2023-10-13 23:00:47 (proper publish date)`

Is my query is right? Apart from date, meta data of all listed posts are correct (title, author etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the date functions reference the global `$post` variable, but from your code the `$post` variable is not being used, so that's why the date is wrong.

Try this (untested):

```php
foreach ( $total_results as $tr ) {
    echo get_the_time( 'j F Y, G:i', $tr );
}
```

Comment: Indeed. I was also thinking that lack of `global $post` instance could be the reason but I figured it out later. I made a change to `<?php echo get_the_date( 'j F Y, G:i', $tr ); ?>` and it works fine. Same as Your proposition with `get_the_time()`. Thanks.